# Converting data from discrete properties of objects in an IEnumerable into an array/series for charting?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, charts, razor

I have an IEnumerable (List<>) of a particular Type.  The Type has a set of properties which I would like to chart as individual series (MVC3/Razor).

Is there a way I can transpose the data in the list of objects into a list of the properties?

e.g.
Given the code below, the end result I am trying to acheive is a set of Series so I have

```
Bucket1: IEnumerable<Date, Value>
Bucket2: IEnumerable<Date, Value>
etc
```

So that I can then chart each series to get a line chart with Date on x and value on y, for (in this example) 3 series/lines. This code works perfectly, but just feels wrong somehow?

```
 var buckets = new List<Bucket>(){
            new Bucket{
                    Date=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3),
                    Bucket1=1000,
                    Bucket2=2000,
                    Bucket3=3000},
                new Bucket{
                    Date=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2),
                    Bucket1=1000,
                    Bucket2=2020,
                    Bucket3=3300},
                new Bucket{
                    Date=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1),
                    Bucket1=1000,
                    Bucket2=2040,
                    Bucket3=3600}
        };

        var chart = new Chart(){ Height = 400, Width = 600 };
        var area = new ChartArea();
        chart.ChartAreas.Add(area);

        var series1 = chart.Series.Add("Bucket 1");
        var series2 = chart.Series.Add("Bucket 2");
        var series3 = chart.Series.Add("Bucket 3");
        foreach (var series in chart.Series)
        {
            series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
        }

        foreach (var item in buckets)
        {
            series1.Points.AddXY(item.Date, item.Bucket1);
            series2.Points.AddXY(item.Date, item.Bucket2);
            series3.Points.AddXY(item.Date, item.Bucket3);
        }
```

Comment: The code is not really 'wrong'. You might be able to shorten it with a Linq GroupBy but that depends on the formats that the Series accept. Just leave it.

Comment: Agreed its not really "wrong"...just seems really clunky.

Comment: Post the Bucket class and explain what are you trying achieve please. Should each bucket class belong to one day? Should each bucket entry(bucket1, bucket2, bucket3) have its own date?

Comment: Bucket class is what you see here - one per date.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Could you add an answer - I looked around, messed around and came to the conclusion that there was no way to make this any "cleaner".  I added a bit of linq to get the series names from an enum, but that's all I could really do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments posted I kept my original code and don't think there's an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

What about just using a Lambda expression for each serie (code below was not tested - it's just a prototype):

```
var series1 = buckets.Select(b => new { b.Date, b.Bucket1 });
var series2 = buckets.Select(b => new { b.Date, b.Bucket2 });
```